# Searching through a list for numbers adding up to a sum in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, math, numbers, sum

I have the user inputting a set of numbers in the range of 1 to 19... and need to find as many as possible of them that add up to 40, each number can only be used once.

So say the list is:
19, 17, 11, 13, 8, 9, 7 ,5 ,10 ,16 ,14 ,8 ,7 ,3.

Then the output should be:
19, 11, 10
16, 14, 7, 3
17, 8, 8, 7

With 13, 9 and 5 left in the list.

I found some suggestions but they seemed to only look for one match, and I made an attempt at my own, but its still lacking some refinement.

```
    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Copy the list to a new list:
        List<int> lookInto = new List<int>();
        foreach(int i in weaponList)
        {
            lookInto.Add(i);
        }

        int lookFor = 40;
        while (lookFor > 0)
        {
            lookFor = Search(lookInto, lookFor);
        }
        if (lookFor != -1)
        {
            listSell.Items.Add(answer);
        }
    }

    private int Search(List<int> hay, int needle)
    {
        int lowestValue = hay.Min();
        int highestValue = hay.Max();

        if (hay.BinarySearch(needle) > 0)
        {
            int index = hay.BinarySearch(needle);

            if (answer == "")
            {
                answer += hay[index].ToString();
                needle -= hay[index];
                hay.Remove(needle);
            }
            else
            {
                answer += ", " + hay[index].ToString();
                needle -= hay[index];
                hay.Remove(needle);
            }
        }

        if (needle - highestValue > lowestValue || needle - highestValue == 0)
        {
            if (answer == "")
            {
                answer += highestValue.ToString();
                needle -= highestValue;
                hay.Remove(highestValue);
            }
            else
            {
                answer += ", " + highestValue.ToString();
                needle -= highestValue;
                hay.Remove(highestValue);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i > hay.Count; i++)
            {
                if (needle - hay[i] == 0 || needle - hay[i] > lowestValue)
                {
                    if (answer == "")
                    {
                        answer += hay[i].ToString();
                        needle -= hay[i];
                        hay.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        answer += ", " + hay[i].ToString();
                        needle -= hay[i];
                        hay.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (needle > 0)
            {
                needle = -1;
            }
        }

        return needle;
    }
```

Comment: The question basicly is what would I need to do to find those values like the example. And no, it's not homework it's for a minor program I'm making for myself.

Comment: This question has been asked *dozens* of times on StackOverflow, and was most recently asked earlier this week. Do a search for "Subset Sum Problem" and you will find lots of information on how to solve this problem; it is one of the most heavily studied problems of all time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving soon and can't type of an actual block of code, but here's how you would do this: create a mirrored static array of all the numbers, use a recursive function to step through and attempt to add numbers from that array up until the reach 40, if they pass 40, it'll just return -1, otherwise, all the indexes that are used to reach 40, each time it returns a set of indexes, remove those numbers from the mirrored array so the next iteration won't try to use them and add the numbers to a a list of sets. when the recursive function stops, what you have left in the main array are the unused numbers, and the list of sets will contain all the found sets.

I hope this helps!